# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', {
    name: String,
    age: {type: Number, default: 20},
    create: {type: Date, default: Date.now} 
});

Cat.findOneAndUpdate({age: 17}, {$set:{name:"Naomi"}},function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});
```

I already have some record in my mongo database and I would like to run this code to update name for which age is 17 and then print result out in the end of code.

However, why I still get same result from console(not the modified name) but when I go to mongo db command line and type "`db.cats.find();`". The result came with modified name.

Then I go back to run this code again and the result is modified.

My question is:  If the data was modified, then why I still got original data at first time when console.log it.

Comment: using  `{new:true}` did not seem to work with `updateOne`, replaced `updateOne` with `findOneAndUpdate` and its working

Answer (score 766, accepted):

### Why this happens?

The **default** is to return the **original, unaltered** document. If you want the new, updated document to be returned you have to pass an additional argument: an object with the `new` property set to `true`.

From the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

> **Query#findOneAndUpdate**
>
> ```
> Model.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, (error, doc) => {
>   // error: any errors that occurred
>   // doc: the document before updates are applied if `new: false`, or after updates if `new = true`
> });
> ```
>
> **Available options**
>
> - `new`: bool - if **true**, return the **modified** document rather than the original. **defaults to false** (changed in 4.0)

### Solution

Pass `{new: true}` if you want the updated result in the `doc` variable:

```
//                                                         V--- THIS WAS ADDED
Cat.findOneAndUpdate({age: 17}, {$set:{name:"Naomi"}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: This appears to be broken for me, it still returns the old document with new: true.

Comment: @PDN What version of mongoose/mongo do you have?  That might be messing with how it works.

Comment: makes sense to me since you already have access to the new document

Comment: it worked for me, I'm using moogose version 4.6.3, thanks

Comment: for those reading here, who might still find that `"new": true` doesn't work, check that the field you update and expect to see in the found object is added to the Schema

Comment: I get the new doc, but `_id` is null, so its not really the new doc.

Comment: Yes, check your schema properly written to do CRUD operations.

Comment: works if i use findAndModify, but not findOneAndUpdate !

Comment: NodeJs MongoDB Native uses - `{ returnOriginal: false }`

Comment: @XCS your solution still works. I can't thank you enough. This is my code

```js

const findOneOrCreateUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { email: data.email },
      {
        $set: {
          data,
        },
      },
      { new: true },
      { upsert: true },
    );
```

Comment: For me works with `{ upsert: true, new: true }` not with `... { new: true },       { upsert: true } ...`. Mongoose 5.9.9

Comment: @user3408530 Upsert tells mongo to create a new document if one does not already exist. So, you are trying to update a document that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I want mongoose to return both, the updated document as well as original one, original for checking if the document was really found and updated and updated one to send to the user back on the front end

Answer (score 157):

For anyone using the Node.js driver instead of Mongoose, you'll want to use `{returnOriginal:false}` instead of `{new:true}`.

**2021 - Mongodb ^4.2.0 Update**
`{ returnDocument: 'after' }`

Comment: Thank you! This works for me mongodb node version 2.2.27

Comment: This is kind of an idiot API. Why not use the same signatures for Mongoose as the native API? Why not return the updated doc by default? Mongoose is one of the more irritating libs I use everyday.

Comment: I'm using `"mongodb": "^3.6.9"` and `{ returnOriginal:false }` is deprecated. 
Use `{ returnDocument: 'after' }` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me.

@kunthet I was actually using this, as the documentation explained that the suggested `{ returnOriginal: false }` is deprecated. But for some reason, I cannot get that to work, while it works as expected using the suggestion.

Answer (score 101):

So, "findOneAndUpdate" requires an option to return original document. And, the option is:

### MongoDB shell

`{returnNewDocument: true}`

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

### Mongoose

`{new: true}`

Ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate

### Node.js MongoDB Driver API:

`{returnOriginal: false}`

**2021 - Mongodb ^4.2.0 Update**
`{ returnDocument: 'after' }`

Ref: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Laravel: `'returnDocument' => FindOneAndUpdate::RETURN_DOCUMENT_AFTER`

Answer (score 47):

By default [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) returns the original document. If you want it to return the modified document pass an options object `{ new: true }` to the function:

```
Cat.findOneAndUpdate({ age: 17 }, { $set: { name: "Naomi" } }, { new: true }, function(err, doc) {

});
```

Comment: why is `_id` null?

Answer (score 19):

Mongoose maintainer here. You need to set the `new` option to `true` (or, equivalently, `returnOriginal` to `false`)

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true });

// Equivalent
await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { returnOriginal: false });
```

See [Mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) and [this tutorial on updating documents in Mongoose](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update#using-modelfindoneandupdate).

Comment: I have mistaken to write returnNewDocument instead of just new. thanks for help!

Comment: How can you use await without async?

Comment: you can't @PeterXX That is just a code snippet.

Answer (score 17):

For whoever stumbled across this using ES6 / ES7 style with native promises, here is a pattern you can adopt...

```
const user = { id: 1, name: "Fart Face 3rd"};
const userUpdate = { name: "Pizza Face" };

try {
    user = await new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        User.update( { _id: user.id }, userUpdate, { upsert: true, new: true }, ( error, obj ) => {
            if( error ) {
                console.error( JSON.stringify( error ) );
                return reject( error );
            }

            resolve( obj );
        });
    })
} catch( error ) { /* set the world on fire */ }
```

Comment: Mongoose will return a promise if you don't provide a callback function. There is no need to create your own promise!

Comment: @joeytwiddle Mongoose **will not** return a Promise if you don't provide a callback. Instead it returns a Query object that provides only a small subset of the Promise API. This is according to the Mongoose documentation.

Answer (score 13):

This is the updated code for `findOneAndUpdate`. It works.

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(    
  { age: 17 },      
  { $set: { name: "Naomi" } },      
  {
     returnNewDocument: true
  }    
)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to return the altered document you need to set the option `{new:true}` API reference you can use `Cat.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes`

Taken by the official Mongoose API http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate you can use the following parameters

```
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options)  // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback) // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)           // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate()                             // returns Query
```

Another implementation thats is not expressed in the official API page and is what I prefer to use is the `Promise` base implementation that allow you to have `.catch` where you can deal with all your various error there.

```
    let cat: catInterface = {
        name: "Naomi"
    };

    Cat.findOneAndUpdate({age:17}, cat,{new: true}).then((data) =>{
        if(data === null){
            throw new Error('Cat Not Found');
        }
        res.json({ message: 'Cat updated!' })
        console.log("New cat data", data);
    }).catch( (error) => {
        /*
            Deal with all your errors here with your preferred error handle middleware / method
         */
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Some Error!' })
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

I know, I am already late but let me add my **simple and working** answer here

```
const query = {} //your query here
const update = {} //your update in json here
const option = {new: true} //will return updated document

const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(query , update, option)
```

Answer (score 4):

Below shows the query for mongoose's `findOneAndUpdate`. Here `new: true` is used to get the updated doc and `fields` is used for specific fields to get.

eg. `findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback)`

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({
      "_id": data.id,
    }, { $set: { name: "Amar", designation: "Software Developer" } }, {
      new: true,
      fields: {
        'name': 1,
        'designation': 1
      }
    }).exec();
```

Answer (score 3):

**2021 - Mongodb ^4.2.0 Update**

This applies to the mongodb node driver, *NOT* mongoose.

It seems like the latest version of the Mongodb node driver uses the following syntax, if you are searching and updating using "collection.findOneAndUpdate":

```
.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, { returnDocument: 'after' | 'before' })
```

Couldn't find the answer here myself while searching, so posting this in case others are in the same situation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30518999)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you check if you're using Mongoose or MongoDB

if using Mongoose - use {new: true}

```
const query = await Model.findOneAndUpdate({filter}, {update}, {new: true});
```

if using MongoDB - use {returnNewDocument: true}

```
const query = await Model.findOneAndUpdate({filter}, {update}, {returnNewDocument: true});
```

Make sure you're using the correct one since, because if you don't, it's just gonna get ommited and you're get the old document.

Answer (score 1):

In some scenarios `{new: true}` is not working.
Then you can try this.

```
{'returnNewDocument':true}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const updatedDocument = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    upsert: true,
    new: true,
  })
```

use this to get update document

Answer (score 0):

```
export function newDocumentOnUpdatePlugin(schema) {
  schema.pre(
    ['update', 'findOneAndUpdate', 'updateOne', 'updateMany'],
    function (next) {
      this.setOptions({ new: true });
      next();
    },
  );
}
```

I have created this plugin if anyone need this functionality across the whole app and want to avoid repetition. Just use this as a [global plugin](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html#global)

Answer (score 0):

This option is  necessary to get updated document instance

```js
{ new: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

In version "mongodb": "^6.3.0", work with the FindOneAndUpdateOptions options, use
`{includeResultMetadata: boolean}`

```
/**
 * Return the ModifyResult instead of the modified document. Defaults to true
 * but will default to false in the next major version.
 */
includeResultMetadata?: boolean;
```