# How to get the id of a created collection in MongoDb with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

How can I get the id when I just saved a nested collection?

Code:

```
(Topic = schemaname from mongoose)
Topic.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: data.topicId}, {data that im inserting in the nested collection})
```

The topic is updated and a nested collection is added, also with an id.
Is there a way to return the id of the inserted nested collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document)

Answer (score 0):

try with query option `{new:true}`

```
Topicopic.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: data.topicId}, {}, {new:true})
```