# Mongoose $push doesn't insert arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my mongoose schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  referral:[{
    id:{type: String},
    name:{type: String}
  }],
  code:{type:String}
});
```

then I try to do something like this

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({code:'123'}, {$push:{'referral':{'id':'49385986','name':'myname'}}},
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

I can see the result, but when I check my db, it's not updated/inserted.

Comment: @chridam where? please point it out

Comment: User.findOneAndUpdate({code:'123'},{})

Comment: @ShantanuMadane I don't get it, can please post an answer?

Comment: @ShantanuMadane Tried to fix the typo, doesn't work too

Comment: I have posted an answer try it

Comment: if you don't see an error, and you get the result, your method is most likely successful, could you paste the log and result into the question

Comment: @Maria Jane : try the code

Comment: @MariaJane..the code that you have posted should work fine..you may not be getting the updated result in your log as you have not include the option `{new : true}` in your query...Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document) stackoverflow post.

Comment: @AnanthPai new simply return the modified data, but my problem is the data did not get modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This:

   User.findOneAndUpdate(
       {code:'123' },
       {
         $push: {
           referral: {
              $each: [ { id: "5", name:"abc" }, { id: "6", name: "xyz" }, { id: "7", name:"pqr" } ]
           }
         }
       },function(err,data){
        if(data){
         console.log(data); 
          }
        else{
        console.log(err);
         }

     });
    );
```

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote if it worked. $ each is used with the push whenever you want to insert one or many values into an array.

Comment: Your code does not work because referal is an array,$each helps in adding elements at proper index but in your code it does not understand at what index the data must be added