# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate returns parameters in different order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently working with mongoose and I've come across something which I find very strange.

My code is as follows:

```js
      Challenge.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.challengeId, users: req.user._id }, { $push: { submissions: submission._id } }, { new: true })
      .then(function(err, challengeUpdated) {
        console.log(challengeUpdated);
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
          console.log('The error is : ');
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Error saving submission' });
        }
         else {
          return res.json(submission);
        }
      })
```

Note how I have `function(err, challengeUpdated)`, in the docs here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate, it says it should be this way round, but when I log them I `err` prints the object, and challengeUpdated prints either undefined / null. Changing the parameters around seems like I hack, so I was wondering whether there was something obvious that I'm doing wrong here.

Note: It is possible for the `req.user._id` not to be in `users`. Which is the error that I'm trying to find.

Looking at the answers to this question: [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document), it seems like the answers have it the same way round as me.

Hoping someone else faced this issue?

Note: I'm using mongoose v5.5.1.

Comment: it said `challenge` is not defined. did you define `challenge` anywhere?

Comment: @Rupesh This is Node.js mongoose code.

Comment: I know but you have to define your `chalange`  .If you haveany schema . then you require that schema like `var Challenge= require('path of your schema');`

Comment: I have temporarily fixed it by switching the arguments around, but would like to double check whether that's Kosher.

Comment: Yes, I require challenge at the top of the file, I didn't include since I didn't think it's directly relevant to the question.

Comment: @SwimmingG because according to error you are not defining the `Challenge` properly , did you check the spelling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using [error-first callback arguments](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) in Promise-based code.

This is how it should be when using `Promise` interface:

```
Challenge.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.challengeId, users: req.user._id }, { $push: { submissions: submission._id } }, { new: true })
  .then((challengeUpdated) => {
    console.log('Success!')
    console.log(challengeUpdated)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('An error occured', err)
  })
```

`function(err, result) { }` is a pattern reserved for callback-style code, not for Promises.

Comment: @SwimmingG As a rule of thumb, when you see `.then()` and/or `.catch()` you should assume you are working with Promises, instead of callbacks.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks again :)