# MongoDB update record and fetch

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In MongoDB (using node.js) I want to update a record and then fetch the returned record.

Can I do this atomically at all?

My searching suggested I could use `findOneAndUpdate`, however my testing with this reveals that it does it in the order that it says, so the "find" part of it is returning the record found **before** the update.

```
> db.demo.insert({ id: 1, data: "abc" })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.demo.findOneAndUpdate( { id: 1}, { $set: { data: "xyz" } } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ae82c1d53d7ae2de3ffbcea"), "id" : 1, "data" : "abc" }
```

How do I find the record **after** the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from mongodb documentations:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    filter,
   update,
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

note: returnNewDocument should be the option to control whether to receive new or old document.

edit: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document) question if you use mongoose

Comment: Note that when using node, instead of `returnNewDocument: true` it should be `returnOriginal: false`