# Unable to Update Mongoose Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose Schema which looks like this

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  username: String,
  image: String,
  userId: String,
  email: String,
  isFormFilled: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
  }, 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

Now, The first time I put value in it, I don't change/put **isFormFilled** value and hence it is value.

Now, somewhere in the app, where I want to change the value of **isFormFilled** to true I am importing it to the given folder containing the route

```
const userBasic = require("../models/user-model.js")
```

and in the route I am doing something like this

```
 userBasic.findOneAndUpdate({userId: newUser.userid},  {
            isFormFilled: true
        },  (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
            console.log(user)
            res.json(req.user)
            }
        })
```

but it doesn't seem to be updating my value to true.

**Question:** Any Idea what I could be doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you just check what userBasic.findOne(...) is returning ? Chances are that you're not getting any object in  userBasic.findOneAndUpdate(...) query

Comment: @RajKumar how can I check that?

Comment: just replace your code with `userBasic.findOne({userId: newUser.userid}).then(user => console.log(user)).catch(err => console.log(err));` and see what is the value of user

Comment: @RajKumar Found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it with Robo 3T, and if it has changed, I have a guess. Mongoose [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) has a parameter called options, and you have to pass a `{new: true}` as an argument (the third argument, before the callback), in order to get the changed document.

Edit: yep, as mentioned in the comments seconds before me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate. Really appreciate your answer. 
Haha, You missed it by seconds but since you are the only one who gave the answer, I will mark it answered. 

btw: what is Robo 3T?

Comment: A GUI tool for mongoDB :)