# mongo is not returning my updated object with the promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, es6-promise

Can anyone help me understand why after update is complete my promise is returning the original (pre-updated) object from Mongo?

To be clear Mongo is being updated, I can see that when I access the database directly (shell), but it seems like the update takes effect after dbModel is returned; which doesn't make sense.

```
updateOneEvent: function (req, res) {
    db.Event.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.params.eventId,
        user: req.session.user._id
    }, req.body)
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `{returnNewDocument: true}` in your options and it will return the new document rather than returning the document before it was updated. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

See [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document) for more details

Comment: Thanks Willis! I guess it makes sense that the default is false, since I'll have access to the updated object in the front end.

Comment: It makes sense, but it's definitely one of those defaults that trips up every single person who's ever done anything on mongo