# Update redux reducer state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I want to update my content on ***same page***, but after server update it shows old data

Name : **Arnold Schwarzenegger**

after i update my data  **Arnold Schwarzenegger** to **Schwarzenegger** using redux-from, Its changed on server but it shows **Arnold Schwarzenegger** on page

After success, i want to replace state with new data, in my case i am using

**EDIT**

---

```
    case 'EDIT_REQUEST':
    return {} // checking the id is same or not using action ID

    case 'EDIT_SUCCESS': // after server update
    return {} // i want to change data using action id, 
unfortunately  action is not available her

    case 'EDIT_FAILURE':
    return {}
```

Comment: when you refresh the page it update ?

Comment: page not refreshing

Comment: i mean when you manually click on the browser refresh

Comment: oh okey, yeah its working, when reload the page

Comment: so my theory is correct you should call your EDIT_SUCCESS action inside EDIT_REQUEST action like the example below

Comment: can you add the actions please to the question i want to take a look

Comment: sure, i will update my question

Comment: what's your reducer initial state structure   ?

Comment: in initial state get all Amenities, it's working fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after i update my data Arnold Schwarzenegger to Schwarzenegger using redux-from, Its changed on server but it shows Arnold Schwarzenegger on page

it's means your server return with old data, please check your update or findOneAndUpdate have `{ new: true }`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document

Answer (score 0):

Check what your server returns and assign that to actions payload then at the reducer do something like this.

case 'EDIT_SUCCESS': 
    return { yourState: action.payload }