# Mongoose querying the array... changing the elements of the array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to remove all the elements from the array in the MongoDB database, then I insert all the new array elements.

My Model is:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email : {
        type : String
    },
    password : {
        type : String
    },
    stocks : {
        type : [String]
    }
}, {versionKey:false}, {_id: false});
module.exports =  final = mongoose.model('users', schema);
```

My stocks array will then have some values. I am trying to remove those values using the following command: 
I read at somewhere in Stack Overflow that to empty your array you can do many things but a set is the fastest way to do this. Please let me know if you know any other way which is better than this.

```
final
  .findOneAndUpdate({email:"abcd@gmail.com"}, {$set:{stocks:[]}})
  .then(()=>console.log("Data removed."))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Once data is removed it means the array will get emptied. Then I assign the whole set of the new array from my local variable like this:

```
const newData = {
  stocks : ["abcd", "wxyz"]
};
```

Now I am trying to assign this new array to my database using this command:

```
final
  .findOneAndUpdate({email:"abcd@gmail.com"}, {$set:{stocks:newData.stocks}});
```

It is emptying the array successfully, but when I am assigning new array it is not working and shows an empty array. Can anyone assist me with this, please?

Comment: This does not reproduce, aside from a possible misuse of `final` where you meant `Pref` as the model. Basically appears to be a typo with no other cause.

Comment: Please check edited question...
Actually it's typo but there must be something other issue...

Comment: Argh! You're looking at the old document. Duplicate of [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document). Missing `{ new: true }`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks bro, I got your point and I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
final.findOneAndUpdate({email:"abcd@gmail.com"}, {$set:{stocks:newData.stocks}}, {new: true})
    .then((doc)=>console.log(doc))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

If you don't use a callback the query is not executed.

> The query executes if callback is passed else a Query object is returned.
>   [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: I edited the answer. The problem is that you miss the callback