# Why does findOneAndUpdate not return document even though the update does happen?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am encountering an issue with findOneAndUpdate operation on nodejs mongodb library, where I cannot tell if an update was done or not.

I wrote a query that can **successfully update the document as expected**, but **value:null was returned after the update**. Ultimately, I would like to distinguish between 3 cases:

1. Document found, cannot be updated
2. Document found and successfully updated
3. Document not found

   ```
   const result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
     { caseId: caseId, list: {$ne: userId}, $expr: {$lt:[ {$size: '$list'}, 'maxLength']} },
     { $push: {assignees: userId}})
   return result.value;
   ```

A little explaination on the query:

I want to append `userId` to the `list` field of a document if

- caseId matches,
- the user is not currently in the `list`,
- the size of the list is smaller than the `maxLength`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document)

Comment: This isn't hidden knowledge. Read the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: As I mentioned nothing is returned in my case, neither the original document nor the updated documents. Having the {returnOriginal: false} won't help in this case. The solution from that post doesn't help

Comment: @Andyk. If nothing is returned then your query isn't matching anything.

Comment: @JacobHull It does match something. When I check the database directly, the new element is appended the first time I run this query. To my surprise, adding a $set operator solved my problem (see answer below for code). I am not so sure why tho

Answer (score 0):

Adding `{new: true}` will return updated document in result

```
const result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { caseId: caseId, list: {$ne: userId}, $expr: {$lt:[ {$size: '$list'}, 'maxLength']} },
  { $push: {assignees: userId}},
{new: true}
)
```

Comment: Nothing is returned in my case, neither the original document nor the updated documents. Having the {returnOriginal: false} won't help in this case.

Comment: I suggested `{new: true}`

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a $set update operator solved my problem.**

It seems that the $push update operator does not trigger an update notification to nodejs. The new element is appended to the collection, but the response treated it as no update done.

```
const result = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { caseId: caseId, list: {$ne: userId}, $expr: {$lt:[ {$size: '$list'}, 'maxLength']} },
  { $push: {assignees: userId}, $set: {caseId: caseId}})
return result.value;
```