# doc.isModified() dosent work with post('findOneAndUpdate')

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The `doc.isModified(`) and `doc.modifiedPaths()` functions doesn't work with the `Schema.post('findOneAndUpdate')`,  I'm trying to return the new updated object but the problem doesn't solved!

```
UserSchema.post('findOneAndUpdate',function(doc){
  console.log(doc.isModified());
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document)