# How to Update only passed value in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have built an API that updates records in MongoDB using mongoose, but currently what happening is if I am passing only `4 field` values in the `JSON file` of postman and try to update then all the values are updating with value null except that 4 fields which I had passed in JSON so can anyone help me how I can pass dynamic field and value that update only passed values of collection not all the fields of collection.

Passes JSON :

```
{
    "preferance_id" : "60fe9ba1766d10d65c64083c",
    "is_active": true,
    "price_blur":true,
    "affiliate_commission":27,
    "language_code": "en"
 }
```

Update call which I have passed in node js

```
transaction.update(PreferencesMasterName,
                    { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(preferance_id) }, {
                        subscriptin_vat : subscriptin_vat,
                        popular_normal : popular_normal,
                        popular_crawled : popular_crawled,
                        price_blur : price_blur,
                        blur_rule : blur_rule,
                        affiliate_commission : affiliate_commission,
                        red_lock : red_lock,
                        automatic_dummy_price : automatic_dummy_price,
                        ...
                        is_active: is_active
                })
```

I want to pass dynamic field and values here instead of this because due to this other values are set will `null` value. So, can anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const data = res.body; // should be an object that needs to updated

 transaction.update({_id: PreferanceMasterName._id}, data, {new: true }, ( error, obj ) => {
            if( error ) {
                console.error( JSON.stringify( error ) );
            }
            console.log( obj );
        });
```

In certain cases `new` doesn't work, you can use : `{ returnOriginal: false }`;
for more details, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document) thread there are multiple ways you can do this.

Please check [update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) how to use it.

Comment: I tired your solution but got an error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value t(ype Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"preferences\`.

Comment: what is `PreferencesMasterName`? I am assuming it to be the `_id` for the document you are updating the value for.

Comment: **PreferanceMasterName** is a collection name of MongoDB. I'm getting login id and login email in response which I'm not storing in DB

Comment: The first object is find query and it has to be correct to run the update query.