# mongoose.findoneandupdate() says updated successfully but no changes occur in database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[image: Code snippet][image: Doc tried editing] [image]

User is the basic schema I created with a name, email, and password. But when I try to update it no errors occur yet the collection in mongodb doesn't change. Tried the {strict: false} option on the schema but sadly that just adds another object to it, debbuging mode didn't help much either so now I am stuck with no clues how to go about solving this. Any advice as to what might be happening? mongoose version is 6.0.12 and mongodb is 4.4.10 if they are of relevance.

```js
// Snippet for the code.
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {updatedUser}, {useFindAndModify: false}, (err) => {
   if(!err){
    console.log("Managed to update")
     res.json({message: "User updated successfully"})
   } else {
    res.json({message: `Something went wrong please try again => ${err} `})
   }
 })
```

Comment: Please do not post images, rather post code

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` returns the updated document when you the option `new` - check that

Comment: @prasad_ I'm not doing anything with the updated document. Problem is the document doesn't update in the first place yet no err is thrown too.

Comment: What is the value in `req.body.id`? What is `_id` in the document?

Comment: @prasad_ the _id property is automatically assigned by mongodb req.body.id is the same id just sent from the client's side

Comment: Have you printed it to the console and verified?

Answer (score 0):

Add `doc` to callback function to see if you are getting updated document and this way you get better error messages.

```js
// Snippet for the code.
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {updatedUser}, {useFindAndModify: false}, (err, doc) => {
   if(!err){
    console.log("Managed to update")
    console.log(doc)
     res.json({message: "User updated successfully"})
   } else {
    res.json({message: `Something went wrong please try again => ${err} `})
   }
 })
```

Comment: Sadly i had to go to my college class and can't check if this works but I will give you an update asap when I get home.

Comment: As mentioned to @Joe returns the matching user but nothing seems to be updating.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is usually and ObjectId, `req.body.id` is usually string, so they don't match.

`findOneAndUpdate` is successful if no matching document is found.

Comment: It returns the user object with the matching _id tag but still doesn't update it. (Add photo in my latest eddit)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document

Answer (score 0):

I misread the documentation page and the whole problem was passing the { updatedUser } needed to be passed without the {}