# findoneandupdate() method updates the database but its response is returned as null in request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a URL shortener. I used a post method to create a short id and insert it in database with following schema: shortenID,url,visitedAt.
Post one is successful and db is also getting updated.
But this redirectToUrl method return url not found. I console logged shortenID, it is there in logs correctly.
Strange thing is I got this log which has null at the end on clog(shortenID).

Also I am following MVC pattern. I am still learning node, incase this info would make any difference

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId('657eaf900cd00ca7d2bc1f4d'),
  shortenID: '6j9qxUFy58',
  url: 'www.google.com',
  visitedAt: [
    {
      timestamps: 1702801419523,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb00b0cd00ca7d2bc1f4f')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702801436348,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb01c50c29d064a9b0736')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702801815416,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb1979745efd6c70277fb')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702802115286,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb2c3e77a78206b63dd26')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702802206807,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb31ee1dd0e92e114fb37')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702802335263,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb39fed9735b46e0cc78e')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702802591675,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb49f0f02975f1ce96300')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702802694745,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb506e3930f6479e4aa59')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702802791317,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb5670ab01847226c6d9a')
    },
    {
      timestamps: 1702803258471,
      _id: new ObjectId('657eb73a52dbb7a72d182143')
    }
  ],
  createdAt: 2023-12-17T08:21:36.795Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-12-17T08:54:18.473Z,
  __v: 0
}
null
```

```js
async function redirectToUrl(req, res) {

    const shortenID = req.params.id

    const urlBody = await URL.findOneAndUpdate({
        shortenID
    },
        {
            $push: {
                visitedAt: {
                    timestamps: Date.now(),
                }
            }
        })
    // console.log(urlBody);
    if (urlBody) {
        // Redirect to the URL if the document exists
        return res.redirect(urlBody.url);
    } else {
        // Handle the case where no document was found
        return res.status(404).send('URL not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate doesn't return updated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document)

Comment: From the [answer in the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811548/1431750), and the tutorial page for [`findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#getting-started), _"By default, `findOneAndUpdate()` returns the document as it was **before**  `update` was applied. You should set the `new` option to `true` to return the document **after**  `update` was applied. You should set the `new` option to `true` to return the document **after**  `update` was applied."_

Comment: @aneroid no, I know this, point is it don't make any difference if I get new or previous doc. But the matter is I am getting null.

Comment: _"But this redirectToUrl method return url not found"_ - that implies your find query is not correct. Just `{ shortenID }` and not `{ shortenID: shortenID }` ? The find `{ x }` syntax only works when _`x`_ is the `_id`, otherwise you have specify the field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`res.redirect()`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect) method:

> Redirects to the URL derived from the specified path.
>
> Redirects can be a fully-qualified URL for redirecting to a different site.
>
> Redirects can be relative to the root of the host name.
>
> Redirects can be relative to the current URL.

The last one is what you have implemented.

Lets say your route is:

```html
http://example.com/shortenID
```

You are taking the `req.params.shortenID` and trying to find the document. Then you are telling express to redirect to here:

```js
return res.redirect(urlBody.url);
```

Well that translates to:

```html
http://example.com/www.google.com
```

Which is being picked up by the `redirectToUrl` function. As you might have guessed by now when you take `req.params.shortenID` it's value is now `www.google.com`. Well, you don't have a document with `{shortenID: 'www.google.com'}` so mongoose can't find the document to update.

Your code then checks `if (urlBody)` which is now false and therein lies the requests final resting place of

```js
return res.status(404).send('URL not found');
```

To fix this problem just save a fully qualified url to the `url` property of the document so instead of `www.google.com` just save `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain this  as well ,
when I console.log(shortenID) , i get
6j9qxUFy58
www.google.com
Why I am getting this www.google.com, like I should be getting only 6j9qxUFy58?

Comment: Those are two different `console.log(shortenID)`. The first one is the one you requested and the second is from the redirect. Remember you redirected to a relative path so `redirectToUrl` fires twice.  Before you fix your code do a `console.log(Date.now())` after `console.log(shortenID)` to see the difference between request times.